# Start indicator when searchbar searching

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I need to create a searchbar to search product . For that I am using searchcontroller and I have an api for searching products by name. I want this: animating indicator when searching from api is processing. How can I solve this?
This is my code for searching from api:

```
func getTovar(){

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "myApiurl")
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
                print(response.result.error!)
                self.indicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

                return
            }

            if let value = response.result.value {
                // handle the results as JSON, without a bunch of nested if loops
                let product = JSON(value)
                for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in product {

                    let img:NSData
                    if let src=subJson["sphoto"].string{

                        if src.containsString("jpg"){
                            let range = src.startIndex.advancedBy(2)..<src.endIndex
                            let substring = src[range]
                            var urlString = "http://admin.unimax.kz/\(substring)"
                            urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
                            if let dataFromURL=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlString)!){
                                img=dataFromURL
                            }
                            else{
                                img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                    }

                    //Do something you want
                    let id=subJson["id"].int!
                    let name=subJson["name"].string!
                    let price=subJson["price"].int!
                    let description=subJson["description"].rawString()
                    self.data.append(Product(id:id,title: name, img: UIImage(data: img), price: price,desc:description!))
                }
            }
    }
}
```

This is my search results updating:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    searchController.searchBar.addSubview(indicator)
    indicator.stopAnimating()

    getTovar()

    for item in data {
        if item.productTitle.containsString(searchController.searchBar.text!){
            filteredTableData.append(item)
        }
    }

    indicator.stopAnimating()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Your WebService call is async. So it's not working in the order you want.

Comment: How i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change you code like this
Change your getTover like this

```
func getTovar(){

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "myApiurl")
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
                print(response.result.error!)
                self.indicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                indicator.stopAnimationg()
                return
            }

            if let value = response.result.value {
                // handle the results as JSON, without a bunch of nested if loops
                let product = JSON(value)
                for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in product {

                    let img:NSData
                    if let src=subJson["sphoto"].string{

                        if src.containsString("jpg"){
                            let range = src.startIndex.advancedBy(2)..<src.endIndex
                            let substring = src[range]
                            var urlString = "http://admin.unimax.kz/\(substring)"
                            urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
                            if let dataFromURL=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlString)!){
                                img=dataFromURL
                            }
                            else{
                                img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                    }

                    //Do something you want
                    let id=subJson["id"].int!
                    let name=subJson["name"].string!
                    let price=subJson["price"].int!
                    let description=subJson["description"].rawString()
                    self.data.append(Product(id:id,title: name, img: UIImage(data: img), price: price,desc:description!))
                }
                indicator.stopAnimationg()
                for item in data {
                    if item.productTitle.containsString(searchController.searchBar.text!){
                        filteredTableData.append(item)
                    }
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
    }
}
```

And change your updateSearchResultsForSearchController like this

```
 func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController){
     searchController.searchBar.addSubview(indicator)
     indicator.startAnimating()
      getTovar()
 }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for answer! But indicator still does not animating

Comment: i forget reload tableview